# DC.JS/Crossfilter: Percentage on y-axis of a bar chart with linear x-axis?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to display percentages on the y-axis of a dc.js barchart that can dynamically change when filtering the chart itself or some other charts.

Here is my case:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(dataCsvInitial);
var all = ndx.groupAll();
var accCredLimDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.acct_curr_crlimit;});
```

Then, I group by bins:

```
var value_range_credlim = maxCredLim - minCredLim;  // defined earlier...
var nb_of_bins_credlim = 50,
    bin_width_credlim = value_range_credlim/nb_of_bins_credlim;
var accCredLimGrp = accCredLimDim.group(function(d) {return Math.floor(d/bin_width_credlim)*bin_width_credlim;});
```

And draw my bar chart:

```
 var creditBar = dc.barChart("#creditDistrib");
        creditBar
            .width(600)
            .height(250)
            .margins({top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50})
            .dimension(accCredLimDim)
            .group(accCredLimGrp)
            .transitionDuration(500)
            .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([minCredLim, maxCredLim]))
            .xUnits(function(){return nb_of_bins_credlim;})
            .elasticY(true)
            .brushOn(true)
            .xAxisLabel("Credit Limit")
```

I succeeded to do what I want initially just by customizing the `yAxis().tickFormat()` attribute of the bar chart, by dividing the tick value by the total number of rows being filtered at the moment:

```
    creditBarChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
            return 100*d/all.value() + '%';
        });
```

And I recompute these ticks every time a transition is being made, because my y-axis is elastic:

```
        creditBar
            .on("pretransition", function(){

            creditBar.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
                if (!creditBar.hasFilter()){
                    return Math.trunc(100*d/all.value()) + '%';
                }
            });
        });
```

As you can see, I don't update the ticks when the bar chart is being filtered. Indeed, when it is filtered I want the ticks to remain unchanged, as the y-axis should not change. However, because I am dividing the tick value by `all.value()` this rule cannot work when filtering the bar chart itself. The displayed percentages are obviously wrong.

This question is quite close to solving my problem: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362475/crossfilter-calculating-percent-of-all-records-with-a-property) but it is applicable only for categorical bar chart...

How can I display percentages on the y-axis ticks, that can change of values when filtering other charts and also when filtering the chart itself?
Is there a sort of `all.value()` that would be computed excluding the effect of filtering a specified chart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the groupAll not to observe the filter on this chart, you should use [the chart dimension's groupAll](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_groupAll) not the one on the crossfilter object. From the docs:

> Note: a grouping intersects the crossfilter's current filters, **except
>   for the associated dimension's filter**. Thus, group methods consider
>   only records that satisfy every filter except this dimension's filter.
>   So, if the crossfilter of payments is filtered by type and total, then
>   groupAll by total only observes the filter by type.

That's kind of a mouthful, but I hope the intention is clear.

```
var accCredLimDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.acct_curr_crlimit;});
var all = accCredLimDim.groupAll();
```

Once you do that, you don't have to put an if statement in your `tickFormat` definition:

```
creditBar
    .on("pretransition", function(){
        creditBar.yAxis().tickFormat(function (d) {
            return Math.trunc(100*d/all.value()) + '%';
        });
    });
```

The if statement was incorrect for a couple of reasons. First, there could be a filter on this chart *and also* filters on the other charts. Second, any accessor you call, like `tickFormat`, needs to return a value every time it is called. But this would return `undefined` if there was any filter on this chart, because that is the default return value in JS.

Comment: Great thanks! This note is actually pretty clear... my understanding was not complete despite coming across this note before.
Also thanks a lot for answering consistently all these questions out there, it is very helpful, especially for non programmers.